# Disable blueprint routes sails js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Hello I have model users, in which there is a foreign key of Orders model.
Now sails will automatically generate route `/users/:id/orders`. I have to disable this route. How to do this ? I have already tried to disable all routes of orders using: `_config : { actions: false, rest: false, shortcuts: false }` but it still doen't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding custom routes, which will overwrite the blueprint action.

Use http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes#?response-target-syntax

```
'/users/:id/orders': {response: 'forbidden'}
```

or http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/routes/custom-routes#?function-target-syntax

```
'/users/:id/orders': function(req, res) {res.forbidden();}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You could control the access to this model through policies.**

For blocking everything put the code below inside your `/config/policies.js` file:

```
Orders : {
  '*': false
},
```

**You could also overwrite the route**
In `/config/routes.js`:

`'/:collection/:id/:model': {response: 'forbidden'}`

**Or you could do the way you've done, disabling the rest routes on this model**

Just make sure you put the whole block, including the export line:

```
module.exports = {
  _config: {
    rest: false
  }
};
```

Comment: I have tried this but this just block /orders & /orders/* . I want to block /users/:id/orders

Comment: Use the _config alternative then but make sure you write this entire block in your model file:

`module.exports = {  _config: {    rest: false  }};`

You just need to block the restful route.